# Exact string matching using regexp in R

Tags: r

I want to exactly match strings using regexp, example

```
data<-c('PQRS_aed','aed_PQRS','aed_PQRS_aed')
str<-'PQRS'
```

I have to match **str** with **data**,

```
grepl('[^a-zA-Z0-9]PQRS[^a-zA-Z0-9]',data)
#FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

it should be **TRUE** for all these cases. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually make sense - it works if Data doesn't include the underscores, but doesn't work if it doesn't include the underscores? Can you give more examples of the strings you'll be matching against, and what you expect to match or not match the regex?

Comment: So what should the result be from your edit?

Comment: @ghub24 Have you tried RichardSciven's method.  It returns TRUE for all the cases.

Comment: RichardSciven's method would match 'aed_PQRS1_aed' also, I am trying to match 'PQRS' within a string, that't the reason I have given the character,numeric class exception. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: I've downvoted this because you can trivially match all your examples with `grepl(".*", data)`.  As Oliver and Richard and akrun have already told you: you need to clearly describe what you expect to not match as well.  If you fix the question I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Downvote from me as well.  You accepted an answer that was pretty much a guess when multiple people asked you numerous times for clarification over the last hour

Comment: What more clarity do you expect Richie? I have said that I need to exactly match 'PQRS'. I am expecting string to be either at the beginning of a word or at the end or separated by underscores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to force a non-work character before the expression. How about

```
data<-c('PQRS_aed','aed_PQRS','aed_PQRS_aed','aed_PQRS1_aed')
grepl("(\\b|_)PQRS(\\b|_)", data)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```